# Can't replace my content with a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, replace

I have an `activity` where I show a map. I want to can change when click an item on my navigation drawer with a different fragment.

I have next main xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.main.activities.Activity_main">

<include layout="@layout/my_bar" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_marginTop ="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
    app:itemIconTint="#000000"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    app:itemTextColor="#000000"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header">
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Bar layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/my_bar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Toolbar  -->

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:titleTextAppearance="@color/text_and_icon_color"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_height="45dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My app"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<include layout="@layout/my_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/my_content"
android:background="@color/window_background_color">


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adView"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I try to replace the map with a fragment :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.main.activities.catalog">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I call with this code:

```
catalog fragment2 = new catalog();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.my_content, fragment2, "fragment2");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But my map isn't replaced with new fragment. Where I do wrong?

Comment: What class and method contains the code which changes the fragment? What happens when you click on the item in the navigation drawer?

Comment: Static `Fragment`s specified in your layout cannot removed/replaced dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MikeM says in a comment to your question, the problem is that `my_content.xml` contains a static fragment specified directly in the XML. `FragmentManager` will not replace such a fragment dynamically at run time. Instead, you should remove the `fragment` tag and add the map fragment dynamically in `onCreate()`. Typically this is done with a `FrameLayout` but I think it will also work with a `RelativeLayout`.

For more information, see the [Fragment Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html).

Comment: Any ref to @Mike M comment?

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin I typed this before I saw his comment. I can add the ref, though.

Comment: My problem is that have more layouts under map fragment in my content layout. Can I create the map fragment on activity and to insert it at beginning of layout?

Comment: @gogoloi Why is this a problem? You should replace the map fragment in the XML with a placeholder `FrameLayout`. Then load the map fragment dynamically similar to the way you are attempting to replace it. If done correctly, the code you use to replace the map with another fragment will work as is.

Comment: Because I am a new developer and don't know how to do it. Can you help me with small sample? Please!

Comment: @gogoloi See [the developer guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) for an example.